JMeter - Assert on a variable
I have a regular expression that returns the below value:

The texts "HRDEV-Scotty-Testing" and "rtc-test-eus-sbc.rtc.hrdev.io" need to be searched in this value.
If found, mark the sample as "Pass" else "Fail".
How do I implement this? Please help.
Thanks for your support.
Regards,
Ajith

Response Assertion has possibility to check the variable:

See How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps for more information on how to apply custom pass/fail criteria to your performance tests using various JMeter Assertions
